Electron beam welding light arcs and insufficient vacuum
I have an electron beam apparatus in a small vacuum chamber. When powering the holder and grid cap to high voltages somewhere between 1-10kV while the filament is heated, the following visually pleasing, but unwanted phenomena occurs:

Initially, a purple cloud forms around the grid-cap and even a purple beam is observed from the heated filament in the grid cap to a copper work-piece. Higher voltage produces a bigger cloud.
The cloud and any electron beam quickly disappears, and instead blue bursts of spot-like light are observed all over the holder sitting at a high voltage. No visible arcs of lightning are formed, but at least some corresponding blue light occurs at the chamber walls. On film it is even possible to capture some blue particle-like balls flying in the chamber.

I believe that the chamber is at an insufficient vacuum, which unfortunately is not possible to measure for the time being. Does this conclusion seem correct, and how are the observations explained if so?

Could you add some annotated photos to your question?

By "insufficient pressure" do you mean too high a pressure (not high enough vacuum)? Because yes, that sounds likely.

@hobbs Yes, exactly so. Interesting it can do that when the distances are few centimeters, more than the arcing distance of the corresponding voltage in atmospheric pressure. The filament also does not burn up.

Sounds like inadequate vacuum. Aside from a lot of heating and other issues from the discharge (which could, I imagine, cause damage), afaiui, you need a pretty good vacuum or the electron beam scatters before enough of it reaches the target. Blue is characteristic of air (due to the N2).

Operating high vacuum apparatus without a vacuum gauge at all, seems irresponsible to me?

@Magemathician Get a T/C gauge, to start. They are inexpensive compared to alternatives and work at levels below 10 Torr where mechanical gauges won't work. I've used Teledyne Hastings type DV-6M-KF-16 before, terminated with a KF-16 flange. (I don't know what flange you need.) This gets down to 10−3 Torr. Perhaps you already know this, though. Also, you are definitely below 100 Torr, though, due to the pink/violet glow. If you can get down to about 5 Torr, or so, a pinkish glow will pull away from the cathode and leave a bright blue glow next to the cathode and a dark "Faraday space" between.

@periblepsis Very interesting, the blue glow did occur in the shadow of the cathode with some strobe quality to it.

@Magemathician There's much more to this. Haven't you studied this, in detail? (I kind of assumed you had.) For example, new things take place below 5 Torr. For example, around 1-2 Torr you may see pink banding/striations/striping at the anode appear right at the same time that the blue glow separates from the cathode. And there's more that starts around 500m Torr (glass tube fluorescence, for example.) These things are very important because they are independent means to judge your gauge that you are using. If you don't know them intimately then that's a problem.

@periblepsis Do you have a source that covers the details?

@Magemathician Experience and old papers and a logbook in front of me. No idea which papers today. It's been a while. But Heinrich Geissler may be a likely source to start.  I also see some information here on Wiki. It mentions the striations and connects them to the anode. It's a start. You will have to do your own searches from here on out, though.
